# Как поменять ссылки у записей только у определенной рубрики wp?

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт, постоянные ссылки вида %postname% и страница записей /blog/
Как мне у рубрики с id 7 slag = "refresh" сделать url site.ru/blog/%postname%  ?
Сейчас идёт site.ru/%postname% у всех статей, но для седьмой надо /blog/%postname%
Даже мыслей нету как это сделать

Сделал так, но теперь по новой ссылке 404, а старые доступны по старому

```
function test($post_link, $post, $leavename) {
  if (in_category('7', $post) || in_category('refresh', $post)) {
    $post_link = home_url('/blog/' . $post->post_name . '/');
  }
  
  return $post_link;
}

add_filter('post_link', 'test', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Можно поставить плагин custom permalinks и руками поменять, если записей не очень много

Answer (score 0):

Создайте [отдельный тип записи](https://misha.agency/course/post-types). post_type=>'blog' потом перенесите записи с той категории в новую.(Можно руками, можна в базе данных переназначить) Создайте 301 редирект что б не потерять трафик на страницах которые станут со статусом 404.

Просто конкретно данную категорию отделить от других вряди получиться... вы тем самым будете ломать вашу текущую настройку WP для пермалинков.

Comment: да это самый простой путь, но на отрез отказались от такого варианта, записи должные быть в записях обычных(

Comment: В `WordPress` все записи есть - `post` так, что по сути ничего не меняеться)  Это задачка на пол-часа дела. Лучшего варианта вы не найдете.